# Join 2 dataframes and get the attribute for each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I have 2 dataframes:

df1

```
df1 = {'ID': [1,1,1], 'FROM': [2,7,8],'TO': [6,8,11],'Type': ['A','B','C'] }

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=df1)

    ID  FROM    TO  type
0   1      2     6     A
1   1      7     8     B
2   1      8    11     C
```

df2

```
df2 = {'ID': [1], 'FROM': [1],'TO': [10],'Interval': ['In'] }
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=df2)

   ID   FROM    TO  Interval
0   1      1    10        In
```

I want to join df2 to df1 and get the attribute of df2:

Like that:

```
   ID   FROM    TO   Type   Interval
0   1      1    2     Nan        In
1   1      2    6       A        In
2   1      6    7     Nan        In
3   1      7    8       B        In
4   1      8    10      C        In
5   1     10    11      C        Nan
```

I have tried something, but I fail and it's bad, and I don't know how to do it.

My code:

```
dfii = pd.concat([c,cc,ccc,cccc,ccccc,cccccc], ignore_index=True)
dfii  = dfii[dfii['FROM_New']!=dfii['TO_New']]

change_places = dfii['FROM_New'] > dfii['TO_New']
dfii.loc[change_places, ['FROM_New', 'TO_New']] = (
    dfii.loc[change_places, ['TO_New', 'FROM_New']].values)

dfii = dfii.sort_values(by=['FROM_New','TO_New'])
dfii  = dfii .drop_duplicates(subset=['FROM_New', 'ID'], keep='first')

dfii = pd.DataFrame(data=dfii)
```

How to do that?

Comment: `c=df1.copy()
cc=df1.copy()
ccc=df1.copy()
cccc=df1.copy()
ccccc=df1.copy()
cccccc=df1.copy()

c['FROM_New']=df1['FROM']
c['TO_New']=df1['TO']
cc['FROM_New']=df1['FROM']
cc['TO_New']=df2['TO']
ccc['FROM_New']=df1['FROM']

ccc['TO_New']=df2['FROM']
cccc['FROM_New']=df1['TO']
cccc['TO_New']=df2['TO']
ccccc['FROM_New']=df1['TO']
ccccc['TO_New']=df2['FROM']
cccccc['FROM_New']=df2['FROM']
cccccc['TO_New']=df2['TO']
`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to merge both dataframes into one like this:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, 'outer')
```

Output:

```
ID  FROM  TO Type Interval
0   1     2   6    A      NaN
1   1     7   8    B      NaN
2   1     8  11    C      NaN
3   1     1  10  NaN       In
```

Comment: sort of, but i also want to return the number of "TO" to the second row and so on.

Comment: it's like to create a new intervale for "FROM" and "TO"